# In android 4.4, swiping app out of recent tasks permanently kills application with its service . Any idea why?

Tags: android, service, android-4.4-kitkat

Unlike previous versions, in 4.4, swiping app out of recent tasks permanently kills app along with its service(like force-stop) even though it's running background services. It shows 0 processes 1 service but service also doesn't work. Ideally it shouldn't kill background service, and it doesn't in versions prior to 4.3. Any idea why is it happening in 4.4?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Got it. Its a bug in 4.4. I tried this and it worked perfectly fine(its a dirty workout though).

Just override this method -:

```
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Log.e("FLAGX : ", ServiceInfo.FLAG_STOP_WITH_TASK + "");
    Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            this.getClass());
    restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

    PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
            getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
            restartServicePendingIntent);

    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}
```

Comment: why are you using the AlarmManager here? Will I have to implement this on a regular service too ?

Comment: I am using it because the moment you swipe, android kills everything, including your service and then there is no way to restart your service. By setting alarm, I am ensuring restart of service.

Comment: I upvoted ... but how can I accept the answer ? its your question :P

Comment: haha dude it's your question. only you have the power to accept :P

Comment: Its my question, thats why I can't accept it. :P
Anyways! :-D

Comment: Deleting these comments, else people will spam it. :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43501/discussion-between-vipul-j-and-user2247689)

Comment: @VipulJ you can accept your answer, but in two days from asking it.

Comment: @Vipul - What is the source of the information regarding the new 4.4 behavior of swiping aside recent apps? Did you read an official documentation or is it just personal experience?

Comment: This is what I got to know after playing a lot. Didnt find anything that time.

Answer (score 4):

From this issue [Foreground service killed when receiving broadcast after acitivty swiped away in task list](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53313)

Here is the solution

In the foreground service:

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved( Intent rootIntent ) {
   Intent intent = new Intent( this, DummyActivity.class );
   intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
   startActivity( intent );
}
```

In the manifest:

```
<activity
android:name=".DummyActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
android:enabled="true"
android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
android:noHistory="true"
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
android:alwaysRetainTaskState="false"
android:stateNotNeeded="true"
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
/>
```

In **DummyActivity.java:**

```
public class DummyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle icicle ) {
        super.onCreate( icicle );
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an solution for android 4.4, not for 5.1 though. My one device with android 6.0 doesn't have the bug so it seems.