# Android Bluetooth Binder is dead

Tags: android, service, bluetooth

I have a Android Service which scans for Bluetooth Low Energy devices. This works but if the app is killed the scan dont work. The service is running but I see in the logcat that the binder for bluetooth is dead.

```
D/BtGatt.GattService(3088): Binder is dead - unregistering client (5)!
D/BtGatt.GattService(3088): stopScan() - queue=1
D/BtGatt.GattService(3088): stopScan() - queue empty; stopping scan
D/BtGatt.btif(3088): btif_gattc_scan
D/BtGatt.btif(3088): btgattc_handle_event: Event 1003
D/BtGatt.GattService(3088): unregisterClient() - clientIf=5
D/BtGatt.btif(3088): btif_gattc_unregister_app
D/BtGatt.btif(3088): btgattc_handle_event: Event 1001
D/BtGatt.btif(3088): btif_gattc_upstreams_evt: Event 1
```

How can i scan for bluetooth devices with a service? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike previous versions, in 4.4 swiping app out of recent tasks permanently kills app along with its service (like force-stop) even though it's running background services. Here you can find a "quick and dirty workaround":
[In android 4.4, swiping app out of recent tasks permanently kills application with its service . Any idea why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677781/in-android-4-4-swiping-app-out-of-recent-tasks-permanently-kills-application-wi)