# Prevent killing of service when clear recent tasks

Tags: java, android, service

My app has Remote, Foreground aidl service which bound to activity. When i clear recent task (by swipe) service destroy. How can i prevent killing of service.

```
  <service android:enabled="true"
                 android:exported="false"
                 android:stopWithTask="false"
                 android:process=":xplay"
                android:name="com.perm.x.Services.PlayingService"/>
```

Here is how i bind (in onResume)

```
 Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this,PlayingService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        bindService(serviceIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Here is how i unbind service (in onPause)

```
unbindService(serviceConnection);
```

Comment: What version of Android does your device have? Does the service eventually get restarted by the system?

Comment: 4.1 Jelly Bean. Yes, the service restarted with notification after about 4 seconds

Comment: Also i test other app. Almost all have the same behavior except Poweramp player. He just ignores killing

Comment: If it gets restarted after a few seconds, is it really a problem?

Comment: @Karakuri Yes it's a big problem
1. All data in service was destroyed
2. Music stopped

Comment: Related: [In android 4.4, swiping app out of recent tasks permanently kills application with its service . Any idea why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677781/in-android-4-4-swiping-app-out-of-recent-tasks-permanently-kills-application-wi)

Comment: @blahdiblah in my case this happens on all os versions

Comment: @dooplaye how u resolved your issue ?

Comment: @ErumHannan
Yes, i have posted answer just

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For preventing service from killing i found one hack (actually i did read it somewhere here)

```
    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DummyActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
```

DummyActivity:

```
public class DummyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        finish();
    }
}
```

And that's it. But there's side effect of this hack - The panel with recents will be immediately hidden after you swipe app of

Comment: i m starting my activity from onRecieve of my alarm now i want my activity should appear in recent list but there is a condition of i ==2 as soon as i ==2 then this activity should be finished and removed from recent list if i use xml property then it is completely hidden from recent list