# Why is my Service stopped when swiping app out of Recents?

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

I declare my Service in the manifest like this:

```
<service
    android:name=".MyService"
    android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

**MyService.java:**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // doing stuff
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);

        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    // does not get called
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        // this method get called when i remove the task from recents
    }
}
```

When i swipe out the app from Recents, `onTaskRemoved` runs as expected, but the `BroadcastReceiver`'s `onReceive` method does not get called anymore.

As far as i know, a `BroadcastReceiver`'s lifetime that's registered dynamically with `registerReceiver` is tied to the object that registered it. I think because of this, if my `Service` is still running, `onReceive` is supposed to be called.

I'm not sure if my `Service` stopped, or the `BroadcastReceiver` got unregistered.

Either way, how can i prevent them from stopping when the task is removed from recents? If i cannot, is there a way to restart it immediately?

Edit:

I'm pretty sure my `Service` is still running, because the OS doesn't try to restart it (as it supposed to do if stopped because of `START_STICKY`), which means the problem is the `BroadcastReceiver` got unregistered. Why? (`onDestroy` does not get called)

Edit2:

Found the problem. It's the device i was testing on. I was using a Xiaomi Redmi Note 2 with MIUI android ROM. Seems when swiping out from recents in MIUI, the OS kills the whole process (pretty much as a task killer does), not just the task.
Testing on my other devices the `Service` is restarted immediately after stopping the task, as it supposed to (because of `START_STICKY`).

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677781/in-android-4-4-swiping-app-out-of-recent-tasks-permanently-kills-application-wi 100% help you..

Answer (score 0):

Check the workaround to handle the service after the restart from the SO link:

[The process of the service is killed after the application is removed from the application tray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592366/the-process-of-the-service-is-killed-after-the-application-is-removed-from-the-a)